# Number not displayed for incoming calls in sony xperia z1

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Whenever I get an incoming call it is just showing unknown. No number is displayed and names are also not displayed though I have saved contacts in my mobile. But no problem for outgoing.

Recently I upgraded it to lollipop. It is fine when I upgraded but from the time I got my sim ported to other network(DoCoMo to airtel), im facing this problem. Did some troubleshooting like restarting the mobile and importing and exporting contacts to sim and internal storage and vice versa and I also saved my contacts in google account .But no luck.

It is driving me crazy. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have chose before upgrade to sync your contacts with google account, you can have this kind of problem. My advice is to turn off sync from google account (in Settings/Accounts), delete your google account from device (reboot, just in case), add again you google account and mark sync options as "on" in Settings/Accounts. It can take a while for contacts to sync back, but this was the way I escaped a touble like yours.